# jQuery jeditable error Object [object Object] has no method 'editable'

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, jeditable

It looks a dummy error for this jeditable object. This is my page

```
  <script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-transition.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-alert.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-modal.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-dropdown.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-scrollspy.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-tab.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-tooltip.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-popover.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-button.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-collapse.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-carousel.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-typeahead.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-affix.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/mgm.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/swimming/classschedules.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/swimming/coaches.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/swimming/programs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/swimming/shoppings.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/swimming/students.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/underscore-min.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/backbone-min.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.jeditable.mini.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>



<div class="edit" id="dev008">click to edit</div>

 $(function() {
     $('.edit').editable('<%= date_swimming_classschedules_path(@date)%>');
 });
```

And I got this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'editable'
```

And I have checked

```
src="/assets/jquery.jeditable.mini.js?body=1"
```

It is reachable. Is there something else should I check to fix this error?

full error message in chrome console

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'editable' er:236
(anonymous function) er:236
y.Callbacks.l application.js:14
y.Callbacks.c.fireWith application.js:14
y.extend.ready application.js:14
M application.js:14
```

**UPDATE.**

I found this line

```
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

just after

```
<script src="/assets/jquery.jeditable.mini.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

is a duplicate of jQuery library. How can I remove this line?

**UPDATE 2**

I am adding related rails code

/app/assets/application.js code

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require underscore-min.js
//= require backbone-min.js
//= require jquery.jeditable.mini.js
```

/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb  code

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

Thanks

Comment: Are there any other errors? (loading errors, for example)

Comment: @JaredForsyth I just updated original post

Comment: Open firebug and see what JS errors are shown in the console.

Comment: @wwli not sure I understand the question "is a duplicate of jQuery how can I remove this line?". you're saying application.js redefines jquery? Then by all means remove it!

Comment: @JaredForsyth yes that is what I meant this is my code in rails layout `<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>   
` I am not sure how to remove that line in rails. All these javascripts references are auto generated by this line

Comment: @wwli sorry can't help you there without looking at your rails code.

Comment: @JaredForsyth  I have updated related rails code in original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find `application.js` (in /assets/) and delete the contents (or do something such that it no longer contains another copy of jquery)

:)

Comment: waw, thanks a lot man! There was a application.js in /public/assets/. After I removed it it is all good now :)